# how to wrap html elements in a box?

Tags: html

I have a search results page and I'd like to wrap each result in a simple box to differentiate between each group but I can't find anything on how to do this.  All I found was w3schools page on the box model and that seems to affect the whole page so it isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by a box?

Comment: just a thin black line around my elements in a box shape.

Comment: Please post the HTML that your results page returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to wrap them in what's called a `div` this is essentially saying to a browser looking at the website "This is a block of something, treat it like that". You can create a div like this

```
<div class="result">Content in here!</div>
```

You can then assign all your divs the CSS class `result` this lets your use CSS code like

```
.result {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this answer. It's pretty much the answer I'd give.

Comment: If all the OP wants is a border around each result, it is completely unnecessary to wrap a div around the result.  Just apply a border to whatever element the result is returned in, but we don't have sufficient information to supply the appropriate CSS yet.

Comment: it's just a series of elements, there is no parent element for each result block.  putting them in a div is probably exactly what's required.